# A short story about an automatic house attending a recently deceased man

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

What is this story called? It is not *There Will Be Soft Rain* by Ray Bradbury, but another short story about a fully automatic house that takes a man out of bed, shaves him, gives him breakfast, puts him in a car that drives him to work where his co-workers discover he has been dead for hours.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is likely the short-story "**Yukitodoita seikatsu**" by japanese science fiction writer **Shinichi Hoshi (1926-97)**. (Possible title translation: well-kept life)

This is made more likely by the OP's nordic name, as the story was printed in the Norwegian SciFi anthology **"Vestenfor Måne"** in **1972**. Here, the title was translated as "automatisk eksistens" (automatic existence). Norwegian internet users will be able to access the full-text [here](https://www.nb.no/items/71619bd8606cfd594e5b1d34eed0dd72?page=133).

The short-story [was also adapted for TV](http://www.iromegane.com/entertainment/king-of-short-short-shin-ichi-hoshi/) in 2007.

The [following summary](http://www.nzasia.org.nz/downloads/NZJAS-Dec03/5.2_8.pdf) was written in 2003 by Sayuri Matsushima:

> in ‘Yukitodoita seikatsu’, a typical morning for a man living in the
>   future is described.  Technology has become so advanced that the man
>   does not need to lift a finger from the moment he wakes up to the
>   moment he arrives at work.  The robotic hand wakes him up, shaves him,
>   showers him, gets his breakfast, and even turns on the TV while he is
>   eating.  He is placed in the travelling pod and automatically conveyed
>   to his office.  It is only when he finally arrives at work that
>   someone notices that he has been dead since the previous night.  The
>   situation is novel and interesting, and the surprise ending conveys
>   irony in the fact that people have become so reliant on technology
>   that they can get dressed and arrive at work as a corpse!

For the Norwegian 1972 anthology, the author gave the following introduction to the story:

> I have lived in Tokyo all my life. The old Tokyo before the war, the
>   burnt ruins of Tokyo after the war and the modern, rebuilt Tokyo. All
>   three phases of this city I have experienced. How will the cities of
>   the future be? How will life be in those cities? My experiences gave
>   me a hint and this eventually grew into the short-story included in
>   this anthology

Comment: And no concept by Shinichi Hoshi that robots that sophisticated can do the man's office work, to?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://archbudgie.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/reddwarfdisappointment.jpg